# Twilio Error 20154 Invalid token claims

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

This is regarding Twilio Programmable Video. I am successfully creating a new room on the server side and then generating the token and adding the video grant to generate the JWT via PHP.

```
$token = new AccessToken(
        $this->TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID, 
        $this->TWILIO_API_KEY, 
        $this->TWILIO_API_SECRET, 3600, 
        $user_id //<--- Identitiy
    );

    // Create Video grant
    $videoGrant = new VideoGrant();
    $videoGrant->setRoom($slot_id);

    // Add grant to token
    $token->addGrant($videoGrant);


    // render token to string
    $jwttoken = $token->toJWT();
```

This is passed to my ReactApp via API call. This JWT is showing the correct RoomName on jwt.io ( http://prntscr.com/j1m161 ) but when trying to use on front end, I am getting this error : TwilioError: Invalid Token claims set ( http://prntscr.com/j1m1uk ). Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I am using Programmable Chat and using PHP code to generate token. I am also facing similar token authorization issue. Looks like there is something issue with PHP SDK. I have been struggling with the token issue for the last two days. Are you using the latest PHP SDK?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the reason is that the clients' identities are written in Unicode. Try to use ASCII identity to solve the problem.